# Wordpress Custom Rest Api - How to get Image Url?

Tags: rest-api

I am creating custom endpoints for my Custom Post Type to remove the unnecessary fields and make request faster. I want to fetch image url from my custom post type. Please check the code for more info. I cant get the Image field. In this [link](https://api.digitalharda.com/wp-json/wp/v2/digievent/), this is what I am getting on default rest api call which is what I want on my custom endpoint**(image url of top_image)**. Please check the method im using and getting null data. Where I am doing wrong ? Please help me.

Here is my Rest api code :

```
function digital_digievent() {
$args = [
    'numberposts' => 99999,
    'post_type' => 'digievent'
];

$posts = get_posts($args);

$data = [];
$i = 0;

foreach($posts as $post) {
    $data[$i]['id'] = $post->ID;
    $data[$i]['EventTitle'] = $post->post_title;
    $data[$i]['EventOrganizeBy'] = $post->organize_by;
    $data[$i]['EventPlace'] = $post->event_place;
    $data[$i]['EventDate'] = $post->event_date;
    $data[$i]['EventTime'] = $post->event_time;
    $data[$i]['EventContent'] = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
    $data[$i]['EventExcerpt'] = $post->post_excerpt;
    $data[$i]['Slug'] = $post->post_name;
    $data[$i]['EventLink'] = get_the_permalink($post->ID);
    $data[$i]['EventDate'] = $post->post_date;
    $data[$i]['EventGuid'] = $post->guid;
    $data[$i]['EventFeaturedImage']['thumbnail'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'thumbnail');
    $data[$i]['EventFeaturedImage']['medium'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'medium');
    $data[$i]['EventFeaturedImage']['large'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'large');
    $data[$i]['top_image'] = $post->ad_1[0]['top_image'];


    $i++;
}

return $data;
```

}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route('myrestapi/v1', 'digievent', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'digital_digievent',
    ]);

});

***`What I want is the image url(guid) of both top_image and bottom_image field for ad_1.`***

Answer (score 0):

`$post->ad_1[0]['top_image']`  will not return you data, because you are not in JS which got response from your REST api which had injected `ad_1` value into object which it returns to you.

In your PHP code `$post` is of type `WP_Post` and it doesn't have `ad_1` in it, that's why you getting nulls. I don't know what `ad_1` is in your data structure. Maybe it's ACF field or just metafield, if it's ACF you need to access it like `get_field( 'ad_1', $post )`.

Check your code which injects `ad_1` value into your current REST route which responds with single item, and do the same for bulk.

Comment: Yes ad_1 is custom post type field which I am getting from advertisement custom post type to this events custom post type with the help of relationship field. To be more specific, advertisement custom post type has 2 top and bottom image field which is file upload field. I want 2 images between the content of events post dynamically because i will have to change all image ads at once later when i want to. And its not ACF, its coming form Pods framework which is custom post type builder just like ACF. :-)